# How do you center the MKMapView map visually when a user location is known or changes?

Tags: iphone, dictionary, mkmapview, center, userlocation

I have read and followed the instructions on [How do I zoom an MKMapView to the users current location without CLLocationManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473706/how-do-i-zoom-an-mkmapview-to-the-users-current-location-without-cllocationmanage)

However, while I do get the current user location, I am unable to actually make the map visually center there.

For example, in the viewDidLoad function, how can I cause the map to center visually around the users known location?  I have pasted the code from CurrentLocation below (See the XXX comment in viewDidLoad

```
#import "MapViewController.h"
#import "PlacemarkViewController.h"

@implementation MapViewController

@synthesize mapView, reverseGeocoder, getAddressButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // XXX HERE: How can I cause self.mapView to actually recenter itself at self.mapview.userLocation.location?


    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    self.mapView = nil;
    self.getAddressButton = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [reverseGeocoder release];
    [mapView release];
    [getAddressButton release];

    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation
{
    self.reverseGeocoder =
        [[[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate] autorelease];
    reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
    [reverseGeocoder start];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSString *errorMessage = [error localizedDescription];
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cannot obtain address."
                                                        message:errorMessage
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}

- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
    PlacemarkViewController *placemarkViewController =
        [[PlacemarkViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlacemarkViewController" bundle:nil];
    placemarkViewController.placemark = placemark;
    [self presentModalViewController:placemarkViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    // we have received our current location, so enable the "Get Current Address" button
    [getAddressButton setEnabled:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 26):

It looks like you can simply use the `centerCoordinate` property of the [MKMapView class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) - the docs say:

> Changing the value in this property centers the map on the new coordinate without changing the current zoom level. It also updates the values in the `region` property to reflect the new center coordinate and the new span values needed to maintain the current zoom level.

So basically, you just do:

```
self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate;
```

Comment: you would want either `mapView.userLocation.coordinate` or `mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate`. The centerCoordinate property is of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`.

Comment: Thanks Guys.  So doing self.mapView.centerCoordinate = self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate; does not work from within viewDidLoad.  It works elsewhere (like when done within reverseGeocodeCurrentLocation) - DT

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need it to be inside `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: You can also use [self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:self.mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate animated:YES] to get this animated

Comment: You may also want to use setRegion: animated: instead of just setting the center coordinate, as you may want the map to zoom in / out as well as moving to where the user location marker is.