# Swift MKMapView KVO

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, key-value-observing

Im trying to create a Key Value Observation for my user current location but I can not get the method of KVO to trigger any information. the delegate for mapView is set.

```
//add observer here
self.mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "userLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new, context: nil)

//my method
  override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print(keyPath!)
    }
```

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473706/how-do-i-zoom-an-mkmapview-to-the-users-current-location-without-cllocationmanage/2578459#2578459 `self.mapView.userLocation.location` is the property that contains the current location coordinates.  You need to observe that property for changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CLLocationManager`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    // You must hold a strong reference to the location manager so make it an instance property
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self

        // Check your app's authorization status
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse, .authorizedAlways:
            // Authorized, start tracking location
            self.startUpdatingLocation()
        case .notDetermined:
            // Not authorized, ask for permission. You can also replace this with
            // locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() if your app needs it
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() 
        default:
            print("permission denied")
            break;
        }
    }

    // MARK: -
    func startUpdatingLocation() {
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
            self.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let lastLocation = locations.last else {
            return
        }

        // now do what you want with the user's location
    }
}
```

Remember to add `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` or `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` to your `Info.plist` to explain why you need to know the user's location. Also prepare for the case when the user does not give you permission to access the phone's location - you have to decide what part of your app can run with knowing the user's location.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know when your current location changes, you can try the [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager) class and use his delegate method

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
       didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
```

I hope it helps :)